# In MASM Assembly Langauge, how would I find the MIN and MAX of values not in an array?

Tags: assembly, x86, max, min, masm

I am currently creating a program that repeatedly asks the user to input a value within a specified range and any value not within the range, will terminate the loop and calculate the sum, rounded average, MIN, and MAX.

I have been able to calculate the sum and average by storing and accumulating them each time the variable is accessed. Though, I am stuck on how to find the MIN and MAX of the valid values entered by the user, to then display it on the screen. My first thought was to create a variable for each value (min and max) that counts the value and only updates the variable if it is greater or lesser than the previously stored value. When attempting the implementation though, I am getting confused. Would I need to compare the user input value to the variable and update it as the MAX gets bigger or MIN get smaller?
Current implementation:

```
_lowerLimit2Valid:
_lowerLimit1Valid:
inc validNumbers                    ;Increment validNumbers by 1 for each valid number.
inc inputNum                        ;Increment inputNum by 1 for each valid number.
add sum, eax                        ;Add the valid user number to sum variable.
cmp min, eax
jg _updateMin
jmp _inputAgain
_updateMin:
mov min, eax
cmp max, eax
jl _updateMax
jmp _inputAgain
_updateMax:
mov max, eax
jmp _inputAgain
```

From the above, I am actually able to update the MIN value correctly by comparing the values and updating only if it's bigger. Now my issue lies in getting the MAX value. I have figured out that the implementation above never reaches my max value as it is only updating my MIN value before looping for another value. I have MIN and MAX initialized to 0 and know how to update with each loop, but how would I grab only the first value if it is the biggest of the bunch? For example, -5, -10, -25, -45 --> Max = -5, Min = -45.  As I've said, from my implementation, I have either gotten 0 (doesn't update) or a number that isn't the MAX.

Comment: `When attempting the implementation though, I am getting confused` where are you confused? Show what you tried

Comment: `for (x : input) { current_max = max(current_max, x); current_min = min(current_min, x); }`  However your loop iterates over input (including by making a system call and converting strings to integers), it's the same problem of cmp/cmov to update each of the two registers or not where you keep the current min and max.

Comment: So if it's not a new min, you jump to `jmp _inputAgain` without checking if it's a new max?    There's your problem.  Don't jump away if you have more work to do this iteration.  Also, use `jng checkmax` or something instead of doing a `jg` over a `jmp`.  One normal way to implement an `if` type of condition is to jump over the body if the condition is false, otherwise execution falls through into it.

Comment: Okay, that was exactly the issue. Felt like I tried a bunch of things but didn't try the most obvious thing. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Updating my code to this:

```
_lowerLimit2Valid:
_lowerLimit1Valid:
  inc validNumbers              ;Increment validNumbers by 1 for each valid number.
  inc inputNum                  ;Increment inputNum by 1 for each valid number.
  add sum, eax                  ;Add the valid user number to sum variable.
  cmp min, eax
  jge _updateMin
  jle _updateMax
  jmp _inputAgain
_updateMin:
  mov min, eax
  jmp _inputAgain
_updateMax:
  mov max, eax
  jmp _inputAgain
```

Makes it work as I intended. Feels like when I look at code for long periods of time I start to forget or miss obvious things.

Comment: That looks highly redundant and still buggy.  The `jmp _inputAgain` after `cmp` is unreachable (one or the other of the two previous JCCs will be taken), so it doesn't matter what's there, might as well be nothing.  And then if you removed `jge _updateMin`, you'd just have a conditional branch over the store of a new `min`, like you want.  But then you'd unconditionally update `max` without having compared against it, only `min`.  So need `cmp max, eax` / `jge _inputAgain` (whether or not you remove the redundant branching on the first `cmp`)